# How probably is a randomly chosen polygon simple?

Tags: probability, euclidean-geometry

A couple of days ago, without any apparent reason, I woke up thinking about the following question: Whenever one randomly chooses $n\in\Bbb N$ ordered points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in the Euclidean plane, what is the probability $P_n$ of the corresponding polygon, i.e., the one with $p_1,\dots,p_n$ as vertices, being simple? Here, being *simple* means that the edges of the polygon do not intersect, except in the vertices.

Here are my attempts to answer it for $n=4$. We start by choosing $3$ ordered points $p_1,p_2,p_3$ in the plane. Clearly, the simplicity of the polygon under construction depends on the choice of the fourth point in relation to the first chosen ones. Indeed, there are some regions of the plane for which this choice will produce a simple polygon, and there are regions for which it won't, as shown in the picture below.

$\hskip6.4cm$[image]

The green areas represent the choices of $p_4$ for which the polygon shall be simple, and the red areas represent the choices of $p_4$ for which the polygon shall be non-simple. Obviously, these regions should be thought as extending to infinity. Thus, each of them have infinite area.

Now come the subtleties I'm not sure how to properly deal with. First, it seems clear that the probabilities of choosing $p_4$ in the red areas are related to the angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$, namely, they should be $\frac{\theta_1}{2\pi}$ and $\frac{\theta_3}{2\pi}$. Also, it seems clear that the area of the triangle $p_1,p_2,p_3$ should be disconsidered, for being finite. But, how to formalize that reasoning?...

Anyway, following it, one might guess that the probability of getting a non-simple polygon *for that particular initial choice of* $p_1,p_2,p_3$ is $\frac{\theta_1+\theta_3}{2\pi}$, which on its turn equals $\frac{\pi-\theta_2}{2\pi}$ since $\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3=\pi$. Thus, this probability would depend only on $\theta_2$ instead of $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

Second, it seems clear that all choices of $\theta_2$ are equally probable. Therefore, since the dependence of the above probability on $\theta_2$ is linear, one might guess that the probability of getting a non-simple polygon *for any initial choice of* $p_1,p_2,p_3$ can be obtained by taking the mean value of $\theta_2$, i.e., $\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence, we arrive at probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of getting a non-simple polygon, thus at probability $P_4=\frac{3}{4}$ of getting a simple one.

Of course, the case $n\ge5$ gets much more complicated. For instance, the "red regions" can start overlapping in non-finite ways, making it unclear, at least in principle, how to deal with the many possibilities that might arise homogeneously, in such a way to get reasonable assertions about probabilities in this context; specially for someone who doesn't know (yet) how to make the reasonings above precise! =D

QUESTIONS

1. Are the above reasonings about probabilities correct? Is the result $P_4=\frac{3}{4}$ correct for $n=4$ ?
2. If they are, how to *prove* them formally?
3. Does anyone know some reference in which the case of arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$ is solved?